# How to get user private message in FB application

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-fql

I have been developing a Facebook application and I want to fetch the private message(chat,replies,inbox etc.) from the user. I have offline access permission to my application..Is that possible to get those details..could any one can sugesst me to get it done

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First i want to bring one thing into your notice.

**offline_access** permission is going **to be deprecated with effect from May 1, 2012**. See [facebook developer documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) for more details.

And more over with the effect of new oAuth dialog, any **extended permission** asked by the application will be displayed separately which gives the user to accept/remove that extended permission and still can able to authorize your app and proceed further.

Read the permissions section in the document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/

Now coming to your question, you can user the `read_mailbox` permission to read the inbox messages of a user. You can find more about the permissions at [facebook developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)